# Agricultural land swapping using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I work for a company that owns agricultural land.
Our new project is consolidating the small plots we own by swapping with other owners.
We have a village were we managed to find all big owners and to map all our plots. All the owners have plots dispersed all over the village.
We want to find or design an algorithm to optimally swap land plots between us and other owners in order to best consolidate.

Is there such a tool in QGIS?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions at https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/305919/115 ?